# isNumeric if then and doesn't work need to simplify

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to simplify this if then statement but when I use if isNumeric (test) and (test) it gives me an error because of the datatype.  I am very new to VB and would appreciate some guidance.  I have several of these text boxes I want to validate with isNumberic.

```
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'Declare variables for pay
    Dim decConneryPay As Decimal = 0
    Dim decLazenbyPay As Decimal = 0
    Dim decMoorePay As Decimal = 0
    Dim decDaltonPay As Decimal = 0
    Dim decBrosnanPay As Decimal = 0
    Dim decCraigPay As Decimal = 0

    'Initial clear lblPayError on each calculation
    lblPayError.Text = String.Empty


    'Convert pay rate text boxes to decimals and * with hours
    'Check txtConneryHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtConneryHours.Text) Then
        decConneryPay = CDec(txtRateSean.Text) * CDec(txtConneryHours.Text)
        lblConneryPay.Text = decConneryPay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

    'Check txtLazenbyHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtLazenbyHours.Text) Then
        decLazenbyPay = CDec(txtRateLazenby.Text) * CDec(txtLazenbyHours.Text)
        lblLazenbyPay.Text = decLazenbyPay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

    'Check txtMooreHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtMooreHours.Text) Then
        decMoorePay = CDec(txtRateMoore.Text) * CDec(txtMooreHours.Text)
        lblMoorePay.Text = decMoorePay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

    'Check txtDaltonHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtDaltonHours.Text) Then
        decDaltonPay = CDec(txtRateDalton.Text) * CDec(txtDaltonHours.Text)
        lblDaltonPay.Text = decDaltonPay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

    'Check txtBrosnanHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtBrosnanHours.Text) Then
        decBrosnanPay = CDec(txtRateBrosnan.Text) * CDec(txtBrosnanHours.Text)
        lblBrosnanPay.Text = decBrosnanPay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

    'Check txtCraigHours for validation
    If IsNumeric(txtCraigHours.Text) Then
        decCraigPay = CDec(txtRateCraig.Text) * CDec(txtCraigHours.Text)
        lblCraigPay.Text = decCraigPay.ToString("c")
    Else
        lblPayError.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblPayError.Text = "Hours worked can only contain positive integers."
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The If statement in the first code is wrong (has an opened bracket which is not closed and refers to the variable txt which is wrong). Also I am not sure why you want to simplify the code below: it includes two If statements for two different situations (analysis of two textboxes); it seems fine to me. You might put the else part together (this is common to both cases) via boolean flag; for example: Dim isWrong As Boolean = False; isWrong = true in each else and a new condition If(isWrong) then ... Color.Red. But this would be more or less the same (= no simplification).

Comment: The problem is I have 8 text boxes I am validating.  Is it ok to use 8 if then isNumeric statements to validate?  It seems I could combine all of these into one because I am checking for the same validation in all boxes.

Comment: First of all bear in mind that what is OK is what is more clear to you (easy to code, easy to extend/understand in the future); the fact of writing more or less code is irrelevant from the execution point of view. Regarding what you are asking, if you have to perform the same analysis and it is possible to iterate through all the elements (are contained in a collection), you should rely on a loop. For example: for each through all the textboxes in the given form. If the analysis is different every time, you would have to set as many conditions/switch statements as textboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the info and taking the time to respond.  I have copied my entire code into the original question for clarification.  Please let me know if/how I can change this to check for non numerical characters as well as negative numbers.  If there are negative numbers or letters I want to display the error message to the lblPayError.  Would using a masked text box make this much easier?

Comment: You are changing different labels in each condition; there is no straightforward way to put this into a loop (these are 8 conditions performing 8 different actions). You might set up some kind of relationship between textbox and label to be edited and then you might create the loop (by assuming that can easily be created; for example: all the textboxes in the form). But at the end, it wouldn't be more simplified than what you have already (all the conditions would be reduced into one but would have to populate the given array setting up the relationships textboxes-labels anyway)...

Comment: ... for a so simple case (just 8 textboxes and labels) I would let it as it is now; why wasting even one second if the resulting code would be identical in performance and more or less the same in length/complexity?

Comment: Sorry for the interruption but is the code above your actual code for those validations? If it is, then clearly, it messes up your code. If I am not wrong, you can condense those method into one.

Comment: @Arman please, interrupt any time you want and for as long as you need; without saying anything

Comment: The names are reasonably constant although do not follow a straightforward pattern (and thus will not perform this implementation for you from scratch) and you might take advantage from that to set up a loop right away without having a set of arrays relating textboxes and labels. Basic idea (you have to build it by your own): For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then -> loop iterating through all the textboxes; for each textbox, you check the name ctrl.Name and extract the bit you want (e.g., Craig from txtCraigHours)...

Comment: This is not a productive approach.  Whenever you have 8 of something then you never think "repeat the code 8 times", you think "use a class!".  This should be a UserControl.  Otherwise little to do with the problem, surely it tells you something better than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Yes Arman this is my exact code.  It compiles and runs fine I was just looking for a better way to check the text boxes for proper input (0-9 only and no letters or negative numbers)

Comment: ... and then use Me.Controls.Find (searchAllChildren set to true) to locate the associated labels/textboxes. By doing this you can reduce all your conditions to just one; although would have to add this "associated label/textboxes locating" algorithm (not too difficult but not completely straightforward either). At the end the resulting length of the code would be more or less the same (performance improvements inexistent; and some effort). Advice: let it as it is now.

Comment: @HansPassant It is not a right approach to the problem at all, no doubt of that. But, on account of the given conditions (by assuming a set of unrelated textboxes and labels with only slightly related names and a working code), letting these conditions is not a bad thing: it is not extremely unclear neither extremely messy.

Comment: Ok I will leave as is thanks.  This is for an intro VB class so I don't want to get to ahead of myself.  Now I need to add another set of if then statements to each textbox to check for overtime vs. normal pay rate :)  Thanks friends!

Comment: No problem. But if this is for an intro VB class, you should note that this is not the way to face a problem; it is just the way to have something working quickly and by assuming that you cannot change the input objects (textboxes/labels). If it is to learn, perhaps you should take Hans Passant's advice and redo everything from scratch (in order to learn properly).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to simplify your code is to get rid of those textboxes and replace them with maskedtextboxes.  This way you can auto-validate all the inputs before you do any calculations.

Second best would probably be to have each one use the same validating event handler and set the e.Cancel to True if the validation fails to simply return the focus back to the offending textbox.  The focus won't leave until the input is valid.

Either way with your inputs validated you can simply set the variables that need setting.